# Storm Incubator and Eclipse Kepler

Tags: apache-storm

Is it possible to import the Apache Storm Incubator (0.9.3) Into Eclipse (Kepler), or should i just stop wasting my time?

I have tried the following, with the following results:

Attempt 1:

1. Clone (git clone ...).
2. Import as maven project into eclipse

A few hundred "LocalCluster could not be resolved to a type" and "LocalDRPC cannot be resolved to a type" errors follow.  I assume that this is something to do with the clojure plugin not found/supported within eclipse, and the fact that Localcluster etc are written in clojure, but I have no idea where to even start to resolve that one.

Attempt 2:

1. Clone.
2. mvn eclipse:eclipse
3. Import project into eclipse

This provides the confusing:
"Project 'storm-core' is missing required source folder: '/home/dev/gitprojects/incubator-storm'"

This is confusing because it is the directory of the project I just imported, so I'm having a hard time seeing how it could be missing.  I can remove it from the build path, but then I get to a few hundred "LocalCluster could not be resolved to a type" errors.

This is just a soul-destroying and/or demoralizing waste of my time right now.  Is there any way of actually importing the incubator project so that it actually works?  Any update I can make to Eclipse to make it work? Any help would be welcomed.

Thanks.

Dave

Comment: Are you trying to actually modify storm source code? Or are you just trying to get started writing a storm topology? If you mean #2, take a look at the [storm-starter project](https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter).

Comment: Have you made any progress with this?

Comment: Not really, but as Kit pointed out I wasn't really trying to modify the storm source, just get the storm starter working and have access to the source within eclipse (both of which I have achieved).  I managed to get a topology up and running, played around with serialization options and got a Kafka spout up and running, so getting the incubator working has been filed under "something to do later".